# How to extract csv data with input() function in python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, input

I am currently trying to make a robust input based graph in python using csv data. I have been able to successfully import the data, and have the input() function work, but I would like for the function to use the matching data point so I can later graph it. Currently, I ask for a date of interest then from that DOI, I would like python to take the subsequent data from the next column and plot that point on a graph. I have tried using a for loop and currently am trying to do this by defining a function. Is it possible to have python do this? or will I need to redefine how to grab the "y" data so to speak?

csv example:
date         value

2006001      12345

2006002      13452

2006003      12567

here is my code so far (for just grabbing the data):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

os.chdir("/Users/misi7940/Downloads/")


masie_df=pd.read_csv("masie (1).csv", skiprows=[0])
#masie_df.info()
x=masie_df[['yyyyddd']]
y=masie_df[[' (0) Northern_Hemisphere']]


def date():
    DOI=input("what is your date of interest?")
    for row in masie_df:
        if DOI == row[1]:
            print(row)


date()
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of csv file ? and what you typed. As a guess you couuld use the groupby function on the input.

Comment: added an example of csv file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your entire script would work, but you would need to use .loc in Pandas to achieve a lookup result.

Here's some (untested) code that might help you along:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ddict = {
    'date':['2006001','2006002','2006003',],
    'value':['12345','13452','12567',],
}
masie_df = pd.DataFrame(ddict)

def date():
    while True:
        print('what is your date of interest? [yyyyddd format]')
        DOI = input('>>> ')
        if len(DOI) == 7:
            for i in masie_df:
                if DOI in masie_df['date']:
                    print(masie_df.loc[masie_df['date'] == DOI]['value'])

        else:
            print('Please enter a valid date format or [Q] to quit.')
            DOI = input('>>> ')
            if DOI.lower() in ['q','quit','',]:
                break

    print('Goodbye!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    date()
```